# PHP form submission issue

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit

This is what I am trying to do here.

1. I have a html form to collect data from users
2. Displaying the output on a textarea after submitting the form
3. Two buttons to process the textarea content :-
   one for downloading the content as text file
   second one for sending the textarea content as email using php

Here, the output textarea is wrapped with a div `output-main` and i dont want to display the this div before the form submit.

Now My HTML code :

```
<div class="emcsaninfo-symcli-main">
    <form  id="main" name="main" action="#text" method="post" > 



    <div class="block-with-text-area">
                        <div class="input-quest-with-text-area">Device List</div>
                        <div class="input-resp-with-text-area"><span><textarea class="textarea" name="devs" ></textarea></span></div>
    </div>


    <div id="devseq" >
            <div class="block">
                        <div class="input-quest">Starting Device</div>
                        <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="sdev" name="sdev" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5"  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['sdev'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['sdev']); }?>" /></span> </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div id="metamemcnt"  >
            <div class="block">
                        <div class="input-quest">Meta member count(Excluding Meta Head)</div>
                        <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="mem_count" name="mem_count" type="text" size="5" maxlength="3"  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['mem_count'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['mem_count']); }?>" /></span></div>
            </div>
    </div>


    <div id="metacnt"  >                
            <div class="block">
                        <div class="input-quest">How many Meta Devices</div>
                        <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="meta_count" name="meta_count" type="text" size="5" maxlength="3"  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['meta_count'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['meta_count']); }?>" /></span></div>
            </div>
    </div>


    <div class="submit-clear">
                        <input  id="generate" type="submit"  name="script" value="create my cli script" />
                        <input type="submit" id="clear" name="clear" value="clear" />
    </div>

    </form>

    </div>
```

Since I dont want to display the output area prior to form submit and I am first checking whether user entered data in the form field, and if yes creating the output `div`

PHP code below

```
<?php   
if((!empty($_POST['sdev']) && !empty($_POST['mem_count']) && !empty($_POST['meta_count']))  || !empty($_POST['devs']) ){

?>          

<div id="output-main">


<?php  
echo '<form action=" " method="post">'; 
echo '<textarea onclick="this.select()" name="output_textarea" id="output_textarea" cols="100" rows="25" readonly>';    

//other PHP Codes here

echo '</textarea>';     

?>  

</div>


<?php                   
echo '<input type="submit" id="download"  value="submit" name="submit"></input>';   

echo '<input class="textbox" type="text" id="email-box" name="email-box" value="Enter Your Email ID here">';

echo '<input type="submit" id="download1"  value="submit2" name="submit2"></input>';



if($_POST['submit2'] == 'submit2') {


$to = $_POST['email-box'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['output_textarea'];
$subject = 'form meta cli script';
$headers  = "From: info@domain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: me@domain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo 'message sent successfully';
}

}

?>
```

Issue that I am facing:

I am able to download the content as txt file but when I a trying to send the content via email, it is not working, it just clear the `output div` section.

But If I remove the the first PHP condition ie,

```
<?php   
if((!empty($_POST['sdev']) && !empty($_POST['mem_count']) && !empty($_POST['meta_count']))  || !empty($_POST['devs']) ){

?>
```

Both download and email function working perfectly. But that time, I can not hide the `output div` section prior to form submit.

I am not understanding whats going wrong here.

I have added

```
 value="<?php if(isset($_POST['sdev'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['sdev']); }?>"
```

to keep the user entered data on its field after form submission. BUt when I am clicking email button, it clearing these fields (download button working fine and it keeps data in field after hitting downloading buttons also)

Comment: I think what one of your problems may be is, and from what I recently learnt is that, variables cannot contain **hyphens/dashes**. For example `email-box`. Try renaming that with an underscore `email_box` and set other variables accordingly.

Comment: @ Fred -ii-     I dont think that is the problem here, because the same script working fine with same variable name when I remove first `if` statement. I will try this method

Comment: And if you change `|| !empty($_POST['devs'])` to `&& !empty($_POST['devs'])` am having a bit of difficulty following the entire structure.

Comment: Tried with different variable, but its not working.I am using `||` because the other three are one set and 1 is a desperate set

Comment: if you change to  `&&` what would happen? you mean the `$_POST['devs]` is an optional?

Comment: @ Leonard Drapeza  : No change. even I tried after removing `$_POST['devs]`.. I believe some problem when I hit the submit button for email but not able to identify